# Change button id and value makes click() event fails

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have a button on my page made like this :

```
<input type='button' class='act' id='save' value='save'/>
```

Within the page I have a couple of click functions eg:

```
$("#save").click(function() {
  alert ('save');
})

$("#update").click(function() {
  alert ('update');
})
```

Using the following jquery elsewhere in the page I'm changing the button value and id.

```
$(".act").attr("id", "save").attr("value", "save");
```

OR

```
$(".act").attr("id", "update").attr("value", "update");
```

Looking at the element I can see the buttons ID and value are being updated.  But the click functions fail following the change.

On first load the 'save' click works as the button has the ID save, following the change the element has got the ID 'update' but the update click isn't triggered.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the `id` of an element isn't a great idea as they are meant to be static.

That being said, your code doesn't work as you attach the event handlers on load of the DOM. Therefore the same event is bound to the element, regardless of its `id`. To achieve what you require you need to use a delegated event handler, like this:

```
$(document).on('click', "#save", function() {
    console.log('save');
}).on('click', "#update", function() {
    console.log('update');
});
```

Note that `document` is used here purely as an example. In production code you should use the closest parent element that's available in the DOM on load of the page.

Comment: Thanks that explains why it wasn't working. sorted now :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
$("#btn1").click(function () {
window.alert("im changing id to btn2 and ho ho ho");
$("#btn1").val("ho ho ho");
$("#btn1").attr("id", "btn2");

$("#btn2").unbind("click").click(function () {
    window.alert("im changing id to btn1 and hey hey");
    $("#btn2").val("hey hey");
    $("#btn2").attr("id", "btn1");    
});
});
```

or delegate method

```
$("#btn1").parent().on("click","#btn1", function () {
    window.alert("im changing id to btn2 and ho ho ho");
    $("#btn1").val("ho ho ho");
    $("#btn1").attr("id", "btn2");   
})
.on("click","#btn2",function () {
    window.alert("im changing id to btn1 and hey hey");
    $("#btn2").val("hey hey");
    $("#btn2").attr("id", "btn1");    
});
```

[How to change the attr and id of a button after clicking? using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097634/how-to-change-the-attr-and-id-of-a-button-after-clicking-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the id id of element, you need event delegation for attaching event to dynamicaaly added element.

But ,there is no need to create different handlers just for toggling value of button. You can simply get the value and alert and set new value according to it:

```
$("#save").click(function() {
 var _this = $(this);
 if(_this.val() == "save"){
   alert('save');
   _this.val('update');
 }else{
   alert('update');
   _this.val('save');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You must read the class. Jquery create the links with the objects when the page load, and cannot ref an object with a new id value.

```
  $(".act").click(function() {
      var idobject = $(this).attr("id");
      alert($('#'+idobject).val());
  });
```